# How to listen to changes in a firestore document using bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc

I want to create a stream to listen to the changes of an array inside a firestore document.
I've implemented the bloc and the function to get the document but when I update the document I don't get the new values

This is my bloc:

```
    on<GetFavoriteEvents>(
      (event, emit) async {
        User user = _authenticationRepository.currentUser;
        await emit.onEach(
            _firestoreRepository.getFavoriteEvents(
                'users/${user.id}', NewEventsModel.fromJson),
            onData: (list) => emit(state.copyWith(favoriteEvents: list)));
      },
    );
```

state

```
@freezed
class EventsState with _$EventsState {
  const factory EventsState({
    List<EventsItemModel>? newEvents,
    @Default(PageState.initial) PageState newEventsStatus,
    List<EventsItemModel>? oldEvents,
    @Default(PageState.initial) PageState oldEventsStatus,
    List<EventsItemModel>? favoriteEvents,
    @Default(PageState.initial) PageState favoriteStatus,
    String? errorMessage,
  }) = _EventsState;
}
```

Stream function:

```
  Stream<List<EventsItemModel>> getFavoriteEvents(
    String path,
    Function converter,
  ) async* {
    var document = await fetchDocument(path);
    var favoriteEvents = converter(document.data()) as NewEventsModel;
    yield favoriteEvents.list;
  }
```

And BlocBuilder:

```
BlocBuilder<EventsBloc, EventsState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                        bool isFavorite =
                            state.favoriteEvents?.contains(event) ?? false;
                        return FilledButton.icon(
                          icon: Icon(
                            FontAwesome5.star,
                            color: isFavorite ? Colors.yellow : Colors.white,
                            size: 14,
                          ),
                          label: Text(
                            isFavorite
                                ? t.events.removeFromFavorites
                                : t.events.addToFavorites,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            if (!isFavorite) {
                              context
                                  .read<EventsBloc>()
                                  .add(AddToFavorite(event));
                            } else {
                              context
                                  .read<EventsBloc>()
                                  .add(RemoveFromFavorite(event));
                            }
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

Any ideas why I don't get the updates?